# Why @Requestparam returns null, but value is filled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have Java with Spring

```
    public String addStudent(@RequestParam(value = "selStud") Long idS,
                             @RequestParam(required = false, value = "selDisc") Long idD,
                             ModelMap modelMap){
        long selectedId = idS;
        long selDiscipline = idD;
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

and this HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add-student}" class="new-student-form" method="post" >
<ul name="selDisc" type="none" th:each="discipline : ${disciplineList.disciplines}" th:value="${discipline.id}">
                <div th:onclick="|javascript:showDiv('${discipline.id}');|"
                   th:text="${discipline.name}"
                     th:value="${discipline.id}"
                   class="discipline-name" >..
                </div>
                <div th:id="${discipline.id}">
                    <ul  class="discipline-info"
                        th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(discipline.students)}">
                        <li th:each="student : ${discipline.students}"
                            th:text="${student.student}" class="studName" name="studName">
                            </li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div name="studOption" th:id="${discipline.id}">
                        <select name="selStud" required >
                            <option th:each="student : ${students}"
                                    th:value="${student.id}"
                                    th:id="${student.id}"
                                    name="studentOption"
                                    th:text="${student.student}">Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="add-student-to-disc" value="Добавить в дисциплину">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>
```

With `@RequestParam(value = "selStud") Long idS` I get `th:value="${student.id}"` from Option, from Select with name "selStud". Example `selectedId = 5`.

But with `@RequestParam(required = false, value = "selDisc") Long idD` I get NULL from `<ul name="selDisc">`. And `@RequestParam(value = "selDisc") Long idD` does not work, because selDisc all time return null.
I have an error "Required Long parameter is not present"

I want to get discipline id, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because there is presumably no parameter in the request called selDisc

Comment: `ul` is not a `<form>` element, so it doesn't POST anything, even if you give it `name` and `value` attributes. If you want to post a form field named `selDisc` with the value of `discipline.id`, then use an [`<input type="hidden" ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) element.

Answer (score 0):

I put
`<input name="selDisc" th:value="${discipline.id}" type="hidden">`
after the first div.

But it works by chance.

Comment: I think it is a comment of some sort.